# Can we use PHP codeigniter as framework for web development and to send API for hybrid app?

Tags: php, codeigniter, phonegap

Can we use PHP codeigniter as framework for web development and to send API for hybrid app ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. I've used this library before: https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

For a more recent approach, if you can, you may use Laravel's Lumen: https://lumen.laravel.com/ specifically designed for API development

Comment: thanks for the info.. My team is planning to use "Phonegap " for developing hybrid app in android and iOS. So as a backend developer , I want to get confirmation that , " PHP API's can be used / called using phonegap or not...?"

Comment: API is merely an HTTP request. can AJAX = can API call

Comment: okay. By the way , you mean to say that " PHP codeigniter can be used with phonegap and there will be no issues " right ?

Comment: Yes. think of it as separate project. your CI is not directly connected with your phonegap project and vice-versa. you will be uploading your CI files into a server where you can access URL publicly (but of course you will be implementing authentications in your API).